# jquery static content in options

Tags: jquery, plugins

I wrote a plugin for two jQuery, first receives the data and adds  in

1.

```
$(function () {

    $.fn.mlData = function(params,callback) {

        $.getJSON(params.url, function(result) {
            callback(result,add);
        });

        function add (dataValue,dataText,dataName) {
            $(mlThis).append('<option dataName="'+dataName+'" value="'+dataValue+'">'+dataText+'</option>');
        }
    }

});
```

and use it

```
$('#select').mlData({
    url:'ajax.php',
},function (result,add) {
    $.each(result.regions,function(k,v) {
        add(v.id,v.region,'region');
        if(v.cities.length > 0) {
            $.each(v.cities, function(i,c) {
                add(c.id,c.name,'city');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**and it works, but 2 plugin to handle the same element, but with the new data**

plugin 2

```
$.fn.mlSelector = function(params) { 
    $('option',this).each(function() {  
        alert($(this).text());  
    }); 
};
```

And does not work, call the second plugin, but he does not see the new

```
$('#ss').mlData({
    url:'ajax.php',
},function (result,add) {
    $.each(result.regions,function(k,v) {
        add(v.id,v.region,'region');
        if(v.cities.length > 0) {
            $.each(v.cities, function(i,c) {
                add(c.id,c.name,'city');
            });
        }
    });
}); 

$('#ss').mlSelect(); // NOT WORK :(
```

Comment: It will be accessible just after the `$.getJSON`'s `success` callback is completed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the second plugin in the callback for the first one.

```
$('#ss').mlData({
    url:'ajax.php',
},function (result,add) {
    $.each(result.regions,function(k,v) {
        add(v.id,v.region,'region');
        if(v.cities.length > 0) {
            $.each(v.cities, function(i,c) {
                add(c.id,c.name,'city');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#ss').mlSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function. The data won't be available immediately after you call it, but after you are done processing the response returned by the server in the `success` callback.

In other words:

```
$('#ss').mlData({
  url:'ajax.php',
}, function(result,add) {
  ...
  /* At his point the data should be available */
  /* You can call it onwards */
  $('#ss').mlSelect();
});
```

That's why you can't see the new data.